# Load text file on Matlab with a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a question about how can I write a code to create a GUI in Matlab. I've created the graphic interface with a simple button. I want that, pressing that button, load a text file and after a loop, load an image and create the different bands (this process is because it's a multispectral image with different bands). This code works well if I execute on a .m file. This is the code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Dates=load ('C:\Users\Desktop\dates.txt');
NombImages=load ('images.txt');
Nimages= numel(Dates);
fileimg=NombImages(1);
fileistr=int2str(fileimg);
image1 = imread(fileistr);
size=size(imagen1);   nrows= size(1);
ncolumns= size(2);
nbands= size(3);

Images = zeros(nrows, ncolumns, nbands, Mimages, 'uint16'); 
imagess = zeros(nrows, ncolumns, nbands);

for image= 1: Nimages
    fileimg=NombImagen(image);
    fileistr=int2str(fileimg);
    imagess = imread(fileistr);
    Images(:,:,:,image)=imagess;   
end

DN= double(Images);

Band1 = Images(:,:,1);
Band2 = Images(:,:,2);
Band3 = Images(:,:,3);

end

% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Maybe it seems a bit complicated but it's because of the format of the images (16 bits, etc.). I don't want to visualize the bands, only load it with that code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Comment: so, what's the question...? do you get any error-messages?

Comment: No, the problem is that when I press the button, I received the following error: "??? Error: File: load.m Line: 113 Column: 1
The function "pushbutton1_Callback" was closed
 with an 'end', but at least one other function
 definition was not." 
 To avoid confusion when using nested functions,
 it is illegal to use both conventions in the same
 file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we go:

you recieve an error-message, which indicates, that there is an "end" at the end of your function (the pushbutton-callback-fcn).

In Matlab it is possible to end functions without ending them with an end :)

When using GUIDE for example, this is the default. GUIDE creates functions without ending them with "end".

So the problem is: if you put an "end"-statement somwhere to end a function, Matlab is expecting an end after EVERY function!!

In your special case:

remove the "end" at the end of your code:

```
...
Band1 = Images(:,:,1);
Band2 = Images(:,:,2);
Band3 = Images(:,:,3);

end%<-this one :)
```

Another option of course is, to an end after every function...

**edit**

to store data within a GUI you can (or should) use the handles-structure. How to use it in detail is explained here:

[TMW: guidata](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)

A short version:

store data within the handles-structure like this:

```
handles.myVar = ...
```

and dont forget to update the structure by this command:

```
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

For you it should look like:

```
handles.Band1=Band1; %or directly: ...=Images(:,:,1);
...
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

and later on you can retrieve the data within another function (that knows about the handles-structure of course!) just like this:

```
handles.Band1
```

Comment: thanks Lucius! I deleted the "end" and in principle, does not generate any error message but it doesn't generate any results. Maybe, do I have to write a command output? I've run the "dbstop if error" command but it doesn't generate any message either.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Lucius! ;) Yesterday I try adding that commmand at the end "set(hObject, eventdata)" but I receive all the time an error but now it works. Thanks!